# How to convert UIImage into byte array in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, nsarray, arrays

I am converting `UIImage`into `byte` like this

```
NSUInteger len = [imageData length];
Byte *byteData= (Byte*)malloc(len);
memcpy(byteData, [imageData bytes], len);
```

when I print this `byteData` in log I see a value like this.

```
(lldb) po byteData
"\377\330\377\340
```

But how can I make a byte array from this?
Please help me.
Thanks

**UPDATE**

this is how our web application pass data to the same service.

```
byte[] fileContent; 
using (var inputStream = file.InputStream)
 { var memoryStream = inputStream as MemoryStream;
   if (memoryStream == null) { memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
   inputStream.CopyTo(memoryStream); } fileContent = memoryStream.ToArray(); 
 }
```

So I want to do the same in my iOS application.

Comment: Why you need to convert uiimage into byte array ?

Comment: I want to send it to my web service and it takes a byte array

Comment: @Irrd Have you find the solution of converting UIImage into byte array.

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert your UIImage into NSData like this......

```
UIImage *imgObj = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.jpg"];

NSData *imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imgObj, 0.9);
```

Answer (score 0):

May be below code could help:

```
@try {
    NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img);
    NSUInteger len = data.length;
    uint8_t bytes = (uint8_t )[data bytes];
    NSMutableString *result = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:len];
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (i) {
            [result appendString:@","];
        }
        [result appendFormat:@"%d",bytes];
    }
    return result;
} @catch (NSException * e) {
    NSLog(@"Exception: %@", e);
}
@finally {
    NSLog(@"finally");
}
```

Comment: why string capacity is len*3?

Comment: you can simply define it as `NSMutableString`@Irrd

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest way...

```
UIImage *img =  [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourimage.png"];

NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img);
```

or

```
UIImage *img =  [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourimage.jpg"];

CGFloat quality = 0.80;

NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img,quality);
```